# Symfony creating Doctrine ORM service

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am writing a very simple API in Symfony 3 for learning purposes. I am trying to cover the services area.

I have a repository where I want to inject Doctrine ORM, to do so I am trying to create Doctrine ORM service in my services.xml file.

Services.xml:

```
    <service
            id="orm.doctrine.service"
            class="Book\BookBundle\DoctrineORM\DoctrineRepo">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
    </service>

    <service
            id="book.repo.create_book_repository"
            class="Book\BookBundle\Repositories\CreateBookRepository">
        <argument type="service" id="orm.doctrine.service" />
    </service>
```

doctrine is a vendor library installed with composer therefore I dont have a class for it in my Bundle. I instead try to refer to it.

DoctrineRepo:

```
<?php

namespace Book\BookBundle\DoctrineORM;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DoctrineRepo extends Controller
{

    private $db;

    public function initDoctrine()
    {
        $this->db = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        return $this->db;
    }

}
```

CreateBookRepository:

```
<?php
```

namespace Book\BookBundle\Repositories;

use Book\BookBundle\Entity\BookEntity;
use Book\BookBundle\DoctrineORM\DoctrineRepo;

Class CreateBookRepository
{

```
private $db;

public function __construct(
    DoctrineRepo $doctrineRepository
) {
    $this->db = $doctrineRepository;
}

public function createRepository()
{

    $product = new BookEntity();
    $product->setTitle('Test Title');
    $product->setAuthor('Leps');
    $product->setReleaseDate(new \DateTime);
    $product->setGender('Scfi');
    $product->setDescription('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.');


    $em = $this->db->initDoctrine()->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();

}
```

}

What am I missing here or not understanding...?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you try to create services for Doctrine yourself instead of using the DoctrineBundle?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to inject the doctrine entity manager in a specific service, have a look to this:

```
<service id="your_service" class="path_to_your_class_service">
     <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
</service>
```

Comment: sorry if been lame but I dont undrstand this but class="path_to_your_class_service"? because I want to inject this service into many different repositories.

Comment: I suppose your service is a class with methods and attributs. For example: MyDoctrineManager.php. It could be stored in this kind of path: `AppBundle\Service`. Thus, the attribut class in your service definition should look like to: `class="AppBundle\Service\MyDoctrineManager"`

Comment: If you have time please look at my question Edits please.

Comment: There are many thing to say... If I understand, you need a Service to persist a new BookEntity object. Your approach is a little bit confused. IMO, the `DoctrineRepo` is useless. Moreover, I really do not understand why you extend `Controller` (You have to know that in a controller you have access to Doctrine EM by this way: `$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()`). So, I'm gonna show you how to create a simple service...

Comment: Any change you could convert this to yml

Answer (score 1):

First, let's configure our service:

```
#../services.xml

<service id="book.manager" class="Book\BookBundle\Manager\BookManager">
    <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
</service>
```

Second, create the service (BookManager)

```
namespace Book\BookBundle\Manager;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Book\BookBundle\Entity\BookEntity;

class BookManager
{
    /** @var Entity Manager */
    protected $em;

    /** 
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }


    public function createBook(BookEntity $book)
    {
        /... a specific logic if you need .../

        $this->em->persist($book);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

And to finish, call your service where you need it (for example in a controller)

```
public function yourSpecificAction()
{
    // We instanciate a new object

    $book = new BookEntity();
    $book->setTitle('Test Title');
    $book->setAuthor('Leps');
    $book->setReleaseDate(new \DateTime);
    $book->setGender('Scfi');
    $book->setDescription('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
    voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.');

    // we call the service
    $bookManager = $this->get('book.manager');

    // we call the method you need
    $bookManager->createBook($book);


    // same to: $bookManager = $this->get('book.manager')->createBook($book);
}
```

Hope it will help you...